# Certain short strings in URL prefix causing 404

Tags: url-rewrite, htaccess

OK, so, been scratching my head all day with this one.

Essentially - I have a Magento installation which sits off the back of a WordPress installation:

- localhost/ [this is where WordPress sits]
- localhost/shop/ [this is Magento's home]

All elements of the website, *except* the catalogue are being handled through WordPress. Magento *only* deals with the catalogue.

The website is to be completely localised for the UK, rest of Europe and US markets. On WordPress, I've achieved this effectively using the qTranslate plugin, so all the following are working:

- localhost/uk/
- localhost/eu/
- localhost/us/

In Magento, I've created 3 storefronts and using the configuration I've managed to make them appear as:

- localhost/shop/uk/
- localhost/shop/eu/
- localhost/shop/us/

However, for consistency I would prefer for the 1st URL segment to *always* represent the locality. I've therefore deployed a little htaccess, edited the relevant configuration (both the Base Link URLs) for each store view and *localhost/eu/shop* & *localhost/us/shop* both work exactly as intended.

*localhost/uk/shop/*, however, causes every page to 404. Initially I tried changing the defaults round (which had no effect), then I tried renaming (and changing the configuration) such that the domain was *localhost/en/shop*. It then worked exactly as intended, and to prove the fault I renamed the (working) */eu/shop/* to */uk/shop/* which caused the same 404s I had previously.

Some other strings I've tried which also cause problems:

- fr
- it
- zd
- xx
- gbr

Can anybody work out what is causing this strange behavior, and suggest how I might go about making it work?

As requested, here's the htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  # Redirect old /shop/uk/ to new /uk/shop
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/shop/([a-z]{2})(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ %1/shop/%2 [R=302,L]

  # Load the right file for new /uk/shop
  RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,3})/shop/(.*)/?$ /shop/index.php?___store=$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,3})/shop/?$      /shop/index.php?___store=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

I should add that this is definitely working in so much as the user is being sent to the store (rather than the WordPress 404 which would otherwise kick in).

Comment: This question is extremely wide. .htaccess code might be helpful, but as far as i see, this is not related to Magento but to a .htaccess config for a special requirement.

Comment: I'll happily update with the htaccess, but the htaccess is definitely working as it is sending me through to the shop rather than WordPress

Comment: Please add it to your answer, formatted if possible.

Comment: Just a quick comment to say I'm pretty sure the answer was given in a later question: 
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36172/how-do-i-set-magento-up-such-that-the-storecode-comes-before-the-path-to-store-i

Answer (score 0):

It seems you dont have all the storeviews you want to use present/configured. a 404 is not a problem but the right thing to show at some cases.
Do you have these stores configured in your backend?

```
fr
it
zd
xx
gbr
```

If so, do you have a Homepage selected for them?

Comment: I've been changing the existing 3 store fronts around. At present I have en, eu and us - which are all working - but as soon as I change en to uk (and change the relevant base link urls) it breaks; the same is true of all the other examples (I have no need for them incidentally, just stuff I've tried). What I need is for either 'uk' or 'gb' to work.

Comment: Please be more specific. I dont quite understand what you mean.

Comment: Apologies, I hit return expecting to get a new line.

Please see my edited response.

Comment: I still dont understand what do you mean. If you have en, eu and us configured and you try to use gb/uk it is normal and expectable to have an error or a 404 page. What do you mean by "it breaks"?

Comment: So, at the moment I have a store view called 'UK' which has the code 'en'. I have set the Base Link URL for the 'UK' store *only* to *http://localhost/en/shop/*. This works just fine (as do the 'us' and 'eu' coded equivalents).

If I change the change the code of 'UK' from 'en' to 'uk' (which is what I would prefer), and also change the Base Link URL for that Store View to *http://localhost/uk/shop/*, I get a 404 error when I go to that URL (or any of the categories and pages which all otherwise work).

Comment: Really interesting...I'm having same problem but in opposite direction - I'm not able to run website with code 'en'. Even tried fresh install (thought it's related to clutter in testing db...no success still /en/ = 404. If i change set_env to other code or change en to eng it's OK. \)